How do I configure DartVM memory growth factor
When developing with flutter dart, I found that when applying for memory, the actual memory applied for is much more. For example, the code for applying for memory is as follow：
class LargeData {
  List<int> _largeList;

  LargeData(int size) : _largeList = List<int>.generate(size, (index) => index);

  List<int> get largeList => _largeList;
}

When I called the LargeData function in main.dart, I found that the memory actually requested by DartVM was much larger than what I wanted to apply for, such as：
LargeData(1000*1000);// When applying for 1M, DartVM actually applied for 5M
LargeData(10*1000*1000); // When applying for 10M, DartVM actually applied for 40M
LargeData(15*1000*1000); // When applying for 15M, DartVM actually applied for 60M
LargeData(20*1000*1000); // When applying for 20M, DartVM actually applied for 80M

It seems that dartvm requested 4 times the memory, I know that the VM will apply for more memory, but I want to adjust this ratio. For example, when applying for 1M, it actually applies for 2M. Can DartVM configure this coefficient and where to configure it?
My flutter version is:

Flutter 3.22.2 • channel [user-branch] • unknown source
Framework • revision 761747bfc5 (4 months ago) • 2024-06-05 22:15:13 +0200
Engine • revision edd8546116
Tools • Dart 3.4.3 • DevTools 2.34.3

I expected that by configuring DartVM, when I request 1M of memory in dart code, the VM actually requests 2M, not larger
